# Number of one-to-one function such that $f(f(x))=x$ and $\left\lvert f(x)-x \right\rvert>2$ for all $x\in\{1,2,...,2n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

One of my friends asked this combinatorics problem, and I am completely lost...

The problem is to find the number of one-to-one function $f:\{1,2,...,2n\}\mapsto\{1,2,...,2n\}$ such that
$$f(f(x))=x$$and$$\left\lvert f(x)-x \right\rvert>2$$for all $x\in\{1,2,...,2n\}$

I tried to make a recurrence relation, directly count it...etc. No methods seems to work for me.

P.S. If this can be solved, can it be extended to the case where $\left\lvert f(x)-x \right\rvert>k$?

Comment: Does $f$ take only integer values at integers?

Comment: Is $f\colon\lbrace 1,2,\dots,2n\rbrace\to\lbrace 1,2,\dots,2n\rbrace\text{?}$ Or should the codomain be something else?

Comment: Ah. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: $f(x)=-\frac1{x}$

Comment: So, $f$ is a permutation, and a product of $n$ disjoint transpositions. There are none for $n=1$ and $n=2$. For $n=3$, We msut have $f(3)=6$, and $f(4)=1$, so there's only one function, $(14)(25)(36)$. For $n=4$, I count ten: $(14)(26)(37)(58)$, which I will write as 14263758 to save work, 14273658, 15263847, 15283647, 16253847, 18253647, 15263748, 15273648, 16253748, and 17253648. Could be a hard problem....

Comment: http://oeis.org/A075851 tabulates the number of permutations with $f(x)-x|>2$ for all $x$, but without the $f(f(x))=x$ condition.

Comment: This is equivalent to counting the number of perfect matchings in $K_{2n} \setminus P_{2n}$, the complete graph with a Hamiltonian path removed (for $|f(x) - x| > k$, you would remove an appropriate power of the Hamiltonian path instead).  However, I don't know whether or not an answer to this question is known, so this may not be very helpful.

Comment: @Shag, I think your perfect matchings have $|f(x)-x|\ge2$, but OP wants $|f(x)-x|>2$.

Comment: @Ger, ah, good point. Remove the square of a Hamiltonian path then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows is definitely more of  a comment, but it may help inspire
more  work on this  interesting problem.  Here is  a Perl  script that
succeeds in computing the number of admissible functions up to $n=8.$

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub enumerate {
    my ($n, $src, $pos, $seen, $mref) = @_;

    if(scalar(keys(%$seen)) == 2*$n){
        $$mref++;
        return;
    }


    return if $pos >= scalar(@$src);

    enumerate($n, $src, $pos+1, $seen, $mref);

    my ($u, $v) = @{ $src->[$pos] };

    if(not(exists($seen->{$u})) &&
       not(exists($seen->{$v}))){
        $seen->{$u} = 1;
        $seen->{$v} = 1;

        enumerate($n, $src, $pos+1, $seen, $mref);

        delete $seen->{$v};
        delete $seen->{$u};
    }

    1;
}

MAIN : {
    my $mx = int(shift || 3);

    for(my $n=1; $n <= $mx; $n++){
        my @srcdata;

        for(my $p=1; $p <= 2*$n; $p++){
            for(my $q=$p+3; $q <= 2*$n; $q++){
                push @srcdata, [$p, $q];
            }
        }

        my $match = 0;
        enumerate($n, \@srcdata, 0, {}, \$match);

        print "$n: $match\n";
    }

    1;
}
```

This produces the following table:

```
1: 0
2: 0
3: 1
4: 10
5: 99
6: 1146
7: 15422
8: 237135
```

It will send us  to [OEIS entry A190823](https://oeis.org/A190823). We
discover  on consulting  this entry  that there  are no  references or
formulae at all.  This is definite evidence for  the problem being new
and difficult. Good luck!

Comment: That OEIS entry also directs us to https://oeis.org/A000806 for the problem with $|f(x)-x|>1$. That problem seems to be very well-studied with lots of facts & links & references, and even an expression in terms of Bessel functions. I wonder whether some of the techniques that have been applied to that problem would also be helpful for the one posed here.